# Loading data with Pandas and performing LDA with SkLearn

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am very new to Data Mining with python. I need to implement Linear Discriminant Analysis on data set which look like this:

```html
0.38769,0.50132,1
-0.86481,0.10141,1
-0.19577,0.22167,1
0.015502,0.1554,2
```

where last digit is a label. I use sklearn and pandas to load my data. I load it this way:

```html
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt

from sklearn.lda import LDA

data = pd.read_csv('data.txt')
print data
```

So when I print my data it looks like that:

```html
0    -0.864810  0.101410  1
1    -0.195770  0.221670  1
2     0.015502  0.155400  1
```

I found LDA example on sklearn official site:

```html
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.lda import LDA
>>> X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
>>> y = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
>>> clf = LDA()
>>> clf.fit(X, y)
LDA(n_components=None, priors=None, shrinkage=None, solver='svd',
  store_covariance=False, tol=0.0001)
>>> print(clf.predict([[-0.8, -1]]))
```

From this example I suppose that I need my labels to be in separate matrix (y), but at this point I am stuck. I have no idea where to go next. I read documentation of pandas and sklearn but they tell me nothing. 
Can you help me by giving guidances and probably examples.

Comment: what are the names of your rows in data.txt

Comment: So have you tried `X = np.array([[-0.864810,  0.101410], [-0.195770, 0.221670], ...)` and `y = np.array([1, 1, ...])`?

Comment: @Farseer, data starts with numbers without names for rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are wanting to do?

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.txt',names=['X1','X2','Y'])
clf = LDA()
clf.fit(data.loc[:,'X1':'X2'].values, data.Y)
```

Comment: Yep, something like that, I was wondering about labels. I though I need to split labels to different array.